# If statement comparions: Matrix and number

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A = [0 4 5 3]` and the the number `B=4`.
No I want to do the following.

```
if A<B
    disp('Something')
end
```

But this doesn't work, Matlab wont compare a matrix to a number. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 4):

Matlab *will* compare a matrix (or, more properly, an array) to a number, the result of that operation will just be another array (of type `logical`). Boolean tests in `if`- and `for`-statements require a single logical to operate on. You need to convert your `logical` array to a single value by using `any()` (will return `true` if *any* of the elements is `true`) or `all()` (will return `true` if *all* of the elements are `true`).

For example:

```
if any(A<B)
    disp('Something');
end
```

---

For more insight into what's going on:

```
>> A = [0 4 5 3]; B = 4;
>> A < B
ans =
     1     0     0     1

>> any(A<B)
ans =
     1

>> all(A<B)
ans =
     0
```

Answer (score 0):

### An addition to the answer by @EelkeSpaak,

If you want to repeat an action each time that the statement is valid, you might need the following script:

```
for ii=find(A<B)
    disp(num2str(A(ii)));
end
```

It depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The result of comparision of `A = [0 4 5 3]` and `B=4` will be a logical matrix:

```
>> A = [0 4 5 3]
A =
     0     4     5     3
>> B=4
B =
     4
>> A<B
ans =
     1     0     0     1
>> class(A<B)
ans =
logical
```

When you use a matrix in `if` statement it will be considered true if it is non-empty and all elements are non-zero

```
>> if A<B, disp('somthing'); end
>> B = 10
B =
    10
>> if A<B, disp('somthing'); end
somthing
```

So it depends what is your expected behaviour of this comparison. You can use other function like `all`, `any` or `isequal`.